# Calculate Time Complexity In This Function

Tags: linked-list, tree, time-complexity, complexity-theory

Given this function (written in pseudocode) what's the time complexity? Trying it out i would say the **time complexity** is **θ(n^3)** since we need to traverse the tree first θ(n) then multiply the contribute of ANCESTOR which is θ(n) and the contribute of ADDTOQUEUE θ(n). Is this correct?

====================================================================

ANCESTOR does a number of operations proportionate to the depth of the node

ADDTOHEAD does a constant number of operations

ADDTOQUEUE does a number of operations proportionate to the lenght of the list

`FUNCTION(T) /* T is a tree filled with integers */

```
L.head = NULL /* L is a new empty linked list (of integers) */
RIC_FUNC(T.root,L)
return L

REC_FUNC(v,L)
if(v==NULL)return
if(ANCESTOR(v))
    ADDTOQUEUE(L,v.info)
else
    ADDHEAD(L,v.info)
 REC_FUNC(v.left,L)
 REC_FUNC(v.right,L)
```

``

Comment: You can calculate the time complexity of recursive functions with the Master-Theorem ( https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms) ).

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you are correct: `O(n^3)`.

**But**, I have a feeling (also not proveable by you pseudo-code) that `ANCESTOR` and `ADDHEAD` are on the contrary sides - which means at the first ran `L` is short and `v` is high therefor `ANCESTOR` will be long and `ADDHEAD` short and after some steps they will gets equal and from that point `v` is lower and `L` is bigger so `ANCESTOR` will be fast but `ADDHEAD` will be long.

If my assumption is correct, and the "speed" of `ADDHEAD` and `ANCESTOR` are the **same complexity** in different direction then you're complexity is `O(n^2)` (as in every node you will get: 1+n, 2+(n-1), 3+(n-2) ... which conclude each step in n+1).